# Capture photo with AVFoundation in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, camera, avfoundation

I'm building a live filter camera app in swift.

I'm changing from AVCaptureVideoDataOutput() to AVCaptureStillImageOutput() to perform the capturing photo function. After I changed, there is no preview view when I open the app.

The capture photo function is working, I can hear the capture sound "Ka" when I click the main group area. There is just no view here.

Here is my full code

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import CoreMedia

let CIHueAdjust = "CIHueAdjust"
let CIHueAdjustFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIHueAdjust", withInputParameters: ["inputAngle" : 1.24])

let Filters = [CIHueAdjust: CIHueAdjustFilter]

let FilterNames = [String](Filters.keys).sort()

class LiveCamViewController :       UIViewController,AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate{
let mainGroup = UIStackView()
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectZero)
let filtersControl = UISegmentedControl(items: FilterNames)
var videoOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addSubview(mainGroup)
    mainGroup.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxis.Vertical
    mainGroup.distribution = UIStackViewDistribution.Fill

    mainGroup.addArrangedSubview(imageView)
    mainGroup.addArrangedSubview(filtersControl)
    mainGroup.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(LiveCamViewController.saveToCamera(_:))))

    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit

    filtersControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0

    let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto

    let backCamera = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)

    do
    {
        let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: backCamera)

        captureSession.addInput(input)
    }
    catch
    {
        print("can't access camera")
        return
    }

    //get captureOutput invoked
    let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
    view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)

    videoOutput.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey:AVVideoCodecJPEG]

    if captureSession.canAddOutput(videoOutput)
    {
        captureSession.addOutput(videoOutput)
    }

    captureSession.startRunning()
}

func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!)
{
    guard let filter = Filters[FilterNames[filtersControl.selectedSegmentIndex]] else
    {
        return
    }

    let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
    let cameraImage = CIImage(CVPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer!)

    filter!.setValue(cameraImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

    let filteredImage = UIImage(CIImage: filter!.valueForKey(kCIOutputImageKey) as! CIImage!)
    let fixedImage = correctlyOrientedImage(filteredImage)

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
    {
        self.imageView.image = fixedImage
    }

}

func correctlyOrientedImage(image: UIImage) -> UIImage {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, false, image.scale)
    image.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height))
    let normalizedImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    let imageRef: CGImageRef = normalizedImage.CGImage!
    let rotatedImage: UIImage = UIImage(CGImage: imageRef, scale: 1.0, orientation: .Right)

    return rotatedImage
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
{
    mainGroup.frame = CGRect(x: 37, y: 115, width: 301, height: 481)
}

func saveToCamera(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    videoOutput.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey:AVVideoCodecJPEG]

    if let videoConnection = videoOutput.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) {
        videoOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection) {
            (imageDataSampleBuffer, error) -> Void in
            let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(imageDataSampleBuffer)
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(UIImage(data: imageData)!, nil, nil, nil)
        }
    }
}

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to capture picture with AVCaptureSession in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28756363/how-to-capture-picture-with-avcapturesession-in-swift)

Comment: You can refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25871513/swift-take-photo-from-avfoundation?rq=1

Comment: if you can hear the sound. probably your code is working for Avfoundation. your view layout (autolayout) or outlets might be messed up,

Comment: you can't beat this sample code .. http://drivecurrent.com/devops/using-swift-and-avfoundation-to-create-a-custom-camera-view-for-an-ios-app/#comment-4686

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture photo or video from camera, then you should use `UIImagePickerController` instead `AVFoundation`. Check [Applce documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/) for more information about it.

**Update :**

Refer [this link](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=UIImagePickerController). It have too many examples of customize `imagePickercontroller`. and you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15865368/how-to-create-a-custom-uiimagepickercontroller-with-full-screen-images-ios)  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15515407/customized-photo-picker-view) answer of stackobverflow.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Sorry, I think uiimagepickercontroller is just allow u to access iphone's own camera. Currently I'm trying to build a fully customized camera in my App.

Comment: you can customize imagePickerController also at some level!!

Comment: do u have idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be because you don't have a frame for the `previewLayer`.

Type this:

`previewLayer.frame = self.view.bounds`

And also explicitly set the video gravity: (I think this is optional)

```
previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill // Or choose some other option if you prefer
```

Comment: Hi, thx for your answer. It works. But the filter is gone.. No live filter cover on the screen.. Should I ask u here, or should I open a new question? Thank u!

Comment: Adding the filters AFTER you set up & present the preview layer should work. They are probably gone since they are added to the view before you show the preview layer and they are below it. So add the `view.addSubview(mainGroup)` below `view.addSubview(previewLayer)` and it should work. If my answer was the right one for you, then please accept it and upvote it. (press the greyed out tick button and the up arrow above the number left to the answer)